# How to Update Stripe Subscription with Python API without Accumulating Price Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, stripe-payments, python-stripe-api

I am using **stripe** API integration to build a python app, I want to be able to allow an user to upgrade their subscription from their current subscription at any point in time and the new subscription would be charged on the next billing interval, I used the modify method of the stripe Subscription object as shown in the documentation, but the issue is that, after modifying the subscription it does not overwrite the previous price object, it simply adds to it, effectively *double-charging* the user on the next stripe subscription billing interval, please can anyone assist with a simple approach as to how to update the price object and lose all references to the previous stripe **price** object in the subscription object

```py
...
# retrieve stripe subscription object
subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve("<stripe_subscription_id>")

# modify the subscription
mod_subscription = stripe.Subscription.modify("<stripe_subscription_id>", items=[{"price":"<stripe_price_id>"}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code snippet that explains a simple way to upgrade subscriptions without the issue stated above

```py
# Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
# See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51KSLReCELlsOU9fXlHPzWJK80JBbyCVgmHoWhtgBPqgkdJSOKDFI11VaUgWRnNEc6YoF8p1ZiG3N6psFg3tcAGQt00KX80pu70'

subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a')

stripe.Subscription.modify(
  subscription.id,
  cancel_at_period_end=False,
  proration_behavior='create_prorations',
  items=[{
    'id': subscription['items']['data'][0].id,
    'price': 'price_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f',
  }]
)
```

for reference visit [Stripe Upgrade Subscription Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade)